# Applications of Canonical Correlation Analysis in real-life problems?

Tags: references, canonical-correlation

I have been exposed to Canonical Correlation Analysis (CCA) a few years ago and I still find it mathematically elegant and beautiful. On Cross Validated there are several interesting posts on CCA, most of them with quite detailed answers. However, from a practical point of view, I still fail to find compelling applications to real-life scenarios.

Apart from applications in psychological studies (e.g. study of correlations between different kinds of intelligence), major applications in other domains seem to be relatively meagre.

I'm writing this post to ask for references (e.g. application papers, review papers, books, etc.) about CCA that you are aware of.

Comment: do you care only about the vanilla Hotelling's CCA or also related merhods? (e.g., regularized versions, pls, ...)

Comment: extensions (regularised, robust, dynamic, etc.) of CCA are also welcomed :-)